# Overlay text over image in css?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Overlay text over img</title>
      <style>
          p{
              position:absolute;
              top: 80px;
              left: 80px;
              color: white;
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="../images/finnish.jpeg" alt="Clean">
        <p>Clean</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is why people place img and text inside a div in html and then in css they set the position of **img** into **relative** and position of the **text** (in this case is p) into **absolute**. I tried the code above, and it still works without setting the position of **img** into **relative**. May someone explain it for me why people doing that?

Comment: add more elements to your page and you will understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set `position: absolute` the element's position is set based on first element with position's relative it finds.
So if you don't set it, it may breakup.

Comment: Can you explain it's in detail, please? Because I don't know what do you mean by saying, "it may break up." Furthermore, do I have to put the img and text are in the same div? I saw people did it regularly when they want to overlay text over img, but I don't know what the point for doing it is?

Comment: when I want to do something like this, I put them in a `div` and set `position: relative` to `div` and `position: absolute` to text.So text is positioned based on `div` and when `div` size changed, the text will be at same position as it was,

Comment: Tks a lot. It is very helpful